# I am facing runtime error while running my flutter WebView project. why Dropdown menu is not selecting an item and Bottombar icons are not appearing

Tags: flutter, webview, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout, bottom-navigation-bar

It's my WebView project. I am facing runtime error while running on emulator .Code is running smoothly but issue is that dropdown button is not selecting any item. Second issue is that icons of bottom Navigation Bar is not appearing excepted selected icon.
[[image: Here is the screenshot of it. enter code here][1]]

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:togoparts_app/splash.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: SplashScreen(),
  ));
}

class TogoParts extends StatefulWidget {
  const TogoParts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TogoParts> createState() => _TogoPartsState();
}

class _TogoPartsState extends State<TogoParts> {
  List<String>list= [
    "My Challenges",
    "Current Challenges",
    "Past Challenges"
  ];
  String? currentItemSelected = "My Challenges";

  int selectedItemIndex = 0;
  late WebViewController webViewController;
  List links = [
    "https://www.togoparts.com/",
    "https://www.togoparts.com/bikeprofile/trides",
    "https://www.togoparts.com/marketplace/browse",
    "https://www.togoparts.com/marketplace/create/",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int? selectedItemIndex = 0;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarColor: Colors.black,
            statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
          ),
          title: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),`enter code here`
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
              elevation: 10,
              icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              dropdownColor: Colors.white,
              items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                      (String dropdownStringItem) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: dropdownStringItem,
                      child: Text(dropdownStringItem),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                // value: _currentItemSelected,
              onChanged: ( String? newValueSelected) {
                _onDropDownItemSelected(newValueSelected!);

                value: currentItemSelected;
              },
            ),
          ),
          actions: [

            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.email,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
          ],
          ),
      ),

        body: Material(
          child: WebView(
            // initialUrl:' https://www.togoparts.com//'
            initialUrl: links.elementAt(selectedItemIndex),
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            // initialUrl: links.elementAt(selectedItemIndex),
            onWebViewCreated: (c) {
              webViewController = c;
            },
          ),
        ),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.wine_bar),
            label: "CHALLENGE",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled), label: "BOARD"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), label: "ME"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined), label: "MARKET"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz), label: "MORE")
        ],
        currentIndex: selectedItemIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        iconSize: 30,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            webViewController.loadUrl(
              links.elementAt(selectedItemIndex!),
            );
            selectedItemIndex = index;
          });
        },
    ),
    );
  }
  void _onDropDownItemSelected(String newValueSelected){
    setState(() {
      this.currentItemSelected=newValueSelected;
    });
  }
}
```

plz review above code and tell me where is the mistake. How can I resolve my issue why dropdown items are not selecting and why  bottom navigation bar icons having disappeard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `selectedItemIndex` from build method.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // int? selectedItemIndex = 0;// remove this
```

And call `value` on `DropdownButton`

```dart
child: DropdownButton<String>(
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
  value: currentItemSelected,
  items: list
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String dropdownStringItem) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: dropdownStringItem,
      child: Text(dropdownStringItem),
    );
  }).toList(),
  // value: _currentItemSelected,
  onChanged: (String? newValueSelected) {
    _onDropDownItemSelected(newValueSelected!);
  },
),
```

Full minimal snippet

```dart
class TogoParts extends StatefulWidget {
  const TogoParts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TogoParts> createState() => _TogoPartsState();
}

class _TogoPartsState extends State<TogoParts> {
  List<String> list = [
    "My Challenges",
    "Current Challenges",
    "Past Challenges"
  ];
  String? currentItemSelected = "My Challenges";

  int selectedItemIndex = 0;

  List links = [
    "https://www.togoparts.com/",
    "https://www.togoparts.com/bikeprofile/trides",
    "https://www.togoparts.com/marketplace/browse",
    "https://www.togoparts.com/marketplace/create/",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // int? selectedItemIndex = 0;// remove this
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: AppBar(
          // backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // color: Colors.black,
                ),
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
              value: currentItemSelected,
              items: list
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String dropdownStringItem) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: dropdownStringItem,
                  child: Text(dropdownStringItem),
                );
              }).toList(),
              // value: _currentItemSelected,
              onChanged: (String? newValueSelected) {
                _onDropDownItemSelected(newValueSelected!);
              },
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.email,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.wine_bar),
            label: "CHALLENGE",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled), label: "BOARD"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), label: "ME"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined), label: "MARKET"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz), label: "MORE")
        ],
        currentIndex: selectedItemIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        iconSize: 30,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            selectedItemIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onDropDownItemSelected(String newValueSelected) {
    setState(() {
      currentItemSelected = newValueSelected;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code dropdown menu items are selecting now but with default blue color. Actually required app bar background color is black. Icons of bottom navigation bar are still disappearing. Kindly resolve this issue.